# Trying to get a wallet at Myetherwallet

Tags: ether

I went on the site, got my Keystore file number and my Private Key number but I cant figure how to get my address? Tryed for hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the view wallet info. Then unlock your wallet with either private key or keystore. (using metamask is a safer way to unlock your wallet, I'd recommend downloading that). Wallet address should be front and center once you unlock.
[image: MEW]